# Read data from file, write result into a new file(java)

Tags: java

I need to read some txt file, get data from it, find out average numbers and then write them into another file. I've done pretty much everything , but can not write needed values in a new file.

```
    public static double KronKesk(double a, double b, double c){
        return (a/2+b+c/2)/2;

    } 


     public static double KronKesk2(double[] b){
        int jag = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            jag++;
        }
        jag = jag - 1;
        sum = ArraySum(b) - b[0] - b[b.length-1];
        return (b[0]/2 + sum +b[b.length-1]/2)/jag;
     }


    public static double ArraySum(double[] a){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sum = sum+a[i];   
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            String filePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TLU\\Semester 2\\ProgPohikursus\\temp";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath  + ".txt"));
            String rida;

            List<Andmed> andmed = new ArrayList<>();
            int ridaCount = 0;
            while((rida = br.readLine()) != null){
                String[] temp = rida.split(",");
                Andmed andmed0 = new Andmed();
                andmed0.setKuupaev(Double.valueOf(temp[0]));
                andmed0.setTemp0(Double.valueOf(temp[1]));
                andmed0.setTemp6(Double.valueOf(temp[2]));
                andmed0.setTemp12(Double.valueOf(temp[3]));
                andmed0.setTemp18(Double.valueOf(temp[4]));
                andmed0.setTemp24(Double.valueOf(temp[5]));

                andmed.add(andmed0);
                ridaCount++;

            }
            System.out.println(andmed);
            br.close();
            File fout = new File(filePath + "_avgtemp"  + ".txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            Andmed andmed0 = new Andmed();

            for (int i = 0; i < ridaCount; i++) {

                double[] andmed1 = {andmed0.getTemp0(), andmed0.getTemp6(), andmed0.getTemp12(), andmed0.getTemp18(), andmed0.getTemp24()};
                double[] andmedFaili = {andmed0.getKuupaev(), KronKesk2(andmed1)};
                bw.write(Arrays.toString(andmedFaili) + "\n");
            }
            bw.close();

        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }




}
```

and another file with getters and setters:

```
public class Andmed {
    private double k;
    private double t0;
    private double t6;
    private double t12;
    private double t18;
    private double t24;
    /*protected static List<Double> allTemp = new ArrayList<Double>();

    public double tempListi(double t0, double t6, double t12, double t18, double t24){
    allTemp.add(t0);
    allTemp.add(t6);
    allTemp.add(t12);
    allTemp.add(t18);
    allTemp.add(t24);
    return 0;
    }*/

    public void setKuupaev(double k){
        this.k = k;
    }
    public void setTemp0(double t0){
        this.t0 = t0;

    }
    public void setTemp6(double t6){
        this.t6 = t6;

    }
    public void setTemp12(double t12){
        this.t12 = t12;

    }
    public void setTemp18(double t18){
        this.t18 = t18;

    }
    public void setTemp24(double t24){
        this.t24 = t24;

    }

    public double getKuupaev(){
        return k;
    }
    public double getTemp0(){
        return t0;
    }
    public double getTemp6(){
        return t6;
    }
    public double getTemp12(){
        return t12;
    }
    public double getTemp18(){
        return t18;
    }
    public double getTemp24(){
        return t24;
    }
}
```

What I have in a first file is:

```
12.01,3,4,5,6,7,8
13.01,4,5,5,4,3,6
...
```

what i need to get into a new file:

12.01, *chronological average of 6 previous numbers*

what do I get for now is:

```
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
[0.0, 0.0]
```

Where is the mistake? :/

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Have you checked if the right values are in the `andmedFaili` array?

Comment: use debugger and see what you are missing. Put breakpoint where you are creating File instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for` loop you are not using your list at all, but an empty `andmed0` variable that you declared just before the loop.

Get rid of that variable and use the actual list :

```
            // Andmed andmed0 = new Andmed(); // no need for that

            for (int i = 0; i < ridaCount; i++) {

                Andmed currentAndmed  = andmed.get(i);
                double[] andmed1 = {currentAndmed.getTemp0(), currentAndmed.getTemp6(), currentAndmed.getTemp12(), currentAndmed.getTemp18(), currentAndmed.getTemp24()};
                double[] andmedFaili = {currentAndmed.getKuupaev(), KronKesk2(andmed1)};
                bw.write(Arrays.toString(andmedFaili) + "\n");
            }
```

Also note that you don't have to use a `ridaCount` variable to compute the size of the list, just call `andmed.size()` instead .

i.e :

```
for (int i = 0; i < andmed.size(); i++)
```

Finally as stated in the comments by @gilfernandes, you may simply use a foreach loop :

```
            for(Andmed currentAndmed : andmed) {

                double[] andmed1 = {currentAndmed.getTemp0(), currentAndmed.getTemp6(), currentAndmed.getTemp12(), currentAndmed.getTemp18(), currentAndmed.getTemp24()};
                double[] andmedFaili = {currentAndmed.getKuupaev(), KronKesk2(andmed1)};
                bw.write(Arrays.toString(andmedFaili) + "\n");
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could also consider to use `for(Andmed currentAndmed : andmed) { ... }`. I do not think that an index `i` is needed.

Comment: @gil.fernandes : Indeed, added to the answer .